# Ubuntu not booting on HP pavilion 17 177-sb with uefi BIOS

Tags: 13.04, uefi

I bought my new laptop yesterday it's a HP pavilion 17 177-sb i believe and it has a UEFI BIOS so I usually install ubuntu the day I buy laptops and I did that this time too. I can only boot and shutdown the OS a few times before it crashes at the gnome logo saying it stopped all the services and then the screen goes black and the windows 8 HP logo appears and it just boots Win8 perfectly fine but ubuntu won't boot I currently have Secure boot turned on(doesn't really matter because it doesn't get fixed when I turn it of) and legacy support disabled! Only a reinstall helps and it just keeps screwing it up

if someone can help me with this I would appreciate it!

thanks,

noahvt

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, solved going to the command line (press <kbd>esc</kbd> at the error message) and ran an update and upgrade of the system, at the restart it worked.
The commands are:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo reboot -h now
```